# href not running after first click but onclick does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this button which opens a modal.

I am opening a new page in the modal, and also doing another api call for processing before calling the new page.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" type='button' id="btn_prev" onclick="prev({{charm_id}})" data-toggle="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#innerModal" href="{% url 'gifcharm:showpreview' %}">Preview</a>
```

This is my button element.

Firstly, I am making the api call using onclick, and then after onclick, href loads the new page.

Now, the thing is,

when I click the button for very first time, both onclick and href works. The onclick does the background processing and href loads the new content nicely.

But after the first call, only onclick works, the href call is never made. As my content changes after some time, I need the href call to be made again for new content to be loaded.

But the same old content keeps on loading, and new content never loads.
Why is it so?

EDIT - Attached JS File.

```
function prev( charm_id){
var imageselected=[];
$("input:checkbox").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.is(":checked")){
        imageselected.push($this.attr("id"));
    }
});

console.log(imageselected);
var url_creategif = "http://localhost:8000/gifcharm/convert_to_gif/" + charm_id;
console.log(url_creategif);

                    jQuery.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url: url_creategif,
                                cache:false,
                                data: {
                                  'images': imageselected
                                },
                                success: function(data){
                                  if(data == "0"){
                                      alert("Problem Creating Gif");
                                  }else{
                                    //alert("Circle Image is successfully created");
                                  }
            }
          });
//url = "http://localhost:8000/gifcharm/showpreview";
};
```

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the `prev()` what does return ? please share code. Also, please consider that the default behavior of the `<a>` tag's onclick and href properties is to execute the onclick, then follow the href as long as the onclick doesn't return `false`

Comment: updated my question, please check

Answer (score 0):

When there is both an on-click event and a href event in the same  tag, the onclick event takes priority.

Add a `return true;` statement at the end of your `prev` function, once you're done with whatever you're doing in there. Once the function returns true, the href will execute. If the on-click callback doesn't return anything or returns false, the href will be ignored.

Comment: Yes. It is working according to that, but only in first attempt. When I click the button second time, it does not call the href/.